# Scatter graph not showing data on Dash

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash, plotly-python

The code takes the dataframe and should present a scatter graph with the x axis being the Near Tenor and the y axis being the Near All-in Mgn. I'd then like to plot on a single graph all of the data points, with them being different colours based on if the data point is Missed (Y) or not (N).

My current code creates the scatter, but does not plot the points onto the chart:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, dash_table
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'CCY Pair': ['EURUSD', 'EURUSD', 'EURUSD', 'EURUSD', 'GBPEUR'],
    'Time': ['13/05/2023', '13/05/2023', '14/05/2023', '14/05/2023', '15/05/2023'],
    'Near All-in Mgn': [43.5, 112.3, 44.2, 89.1, 40.9],
    'Near Tenor': ['1W', '2W', '1M', '1W', '2W'],
    'Missed': ['N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N']
}

df_missedAnalysis = pd.DataFrame(data)

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(children='Application'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id="dropdown",
        options=[{'label': pair, 'value': pair} for pair in df['CCY Pair'].unique()],
        multi=True,
        value="",
        clearable=False,
    ),
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='date-range',
        min_date_allowed=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y').min().date(),
        max_date_allowed=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y').max().date(),
        start_date=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y').min().date(),
        end_date=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y').max().date(),
        display_format='DD/MM/YYYY',
    ),
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.Div([
                html.H3("Missed Trade Margin Analysis", style={'text-align': 'center', 'margin': 'px'}),
                dcc.Graph(id="graph-MissedAnalysis")
            ], style={'border': '1px solid #ccc', 'box-shadow': '0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)', 'padding': '10px'})
        ], style={'width': '50%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
    ]),
    dash_table.DataTable(data=df.to_dict('records'), page_size=10),
])


def get_color_mapping(dataframe):
    color_mapping = {pair: color for pair, color in zip(dataframe['CCY Pair'].unique(), px.colors.qualitative.Plotly)}
    return color_mapping


@app.callback(
    Output("graph-MissedAnalysis", "figure"),
    Input("dropdown", "value"),
    Input('date-range', 'start_date'),
    Input('date-range', 'end_date')
)
def update_figure(dropdown_value, start_date, end_date):
    if isinstance(dropdown_value, list):
        df_missedAnalysis_filtered = df_missedAnalysis[df_missedAnalysis['CCY Pair'].isin(dropdown_value)]
    else:
        df_missedAnalysis_filtered = df_missedAnalysis[df_missedAnalysis['CCY Pair'] == dropdown_value]

    mask = (pd.to_datetime(df_missedAnalysis_filtered['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.date >= pd.to_datetime(start_date).date()) & \
           (pd.to_datetime(df_missedAnalysis_filtered['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.date <= pd.to_datetime(end_date).date())
    df_missedAnalysis_filtered = df_missedAnalysis_filtered.loc[mask]

    color_mapping = get_color_mapping(df_missedAnalysis_filtered)
    colors = [color_mapping[pair] for pair in df_missedAnalysis_filtered['CCY Pair']]

    fig_missedAnalysis = go.Figure()

    for pair, color in color_mapping.items():
        pair_data = df_missedAnalysis_filtered[df_missedAnalysis_filtered['CCY Pair'] == pair]
        fig_missedAnalysis.add_trace(go.Scatter(
            x=pair_data['Near Tenor'],
            y=pair_data['Near All-in Mgn'],
            mode='markers',
            name=pair,
            marker={
                'color': color,
            }
        ))

    fig_missedAnalysis.update_layout(
        xaxis_title="Near Tenor",
        yaxis_title="Near All-in Mgn",
        showlegend=True
    )

    return fig_missedAnalysis


# Run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8053)
```

Comment: Dataframe name in Dropdown options and DatePickerRange options is different with real one. I think you should change from `df` to `df_missedAnalysis`